# How can I set in build.sbt file my local library

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use a library cloned from github in my machine and modified.
And I would like to test my code.

What can i do to set in my build.sbt file

```
name := "Actoverse Demo"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.20"
)

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(actoversePlugin)

lazy val actoversePlugin = RootProject(file ( " /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Bo/Actoverse-Scala/src/main/scala/actoverse" ))
```

to execute instead my local version of library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify this

```
RootProject (uri ("https://github.com/45deg/Actoverse-Scala.git")
```

for this

```
RootProject (file("whateverPath")
```

More info [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration)

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't work.. what can i do ? I edit my Question adding all the build.sbt file.. what i wrong ? Are there other steps that i forgot to do?

Comment: Did you use an absolute path or a relative one? I think it should be absolute

Comment: Yes, it is absolute